# Why is my Hibernate logging so obsfucated?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am logging my HQL by including the following in hibernate.properties

```
hibernate.show_sql = true
```

But the HQL that gets logged is hard to read because it adds a bunch of numbers and underscores all over like this

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        person0_.company_code as company_1_7_0_,
        person0_.person_code as person_co2_7_0_,
   from
        t_person0_ 
   where
        person0_.company_code=?
```

How can I get Hibernate to log more readable HQL?

Comment: Mostly thats how Hibernate works, you can try `hibernate.format_sql = true` for a bit prettier results

Comment: You can try setting `logging.level.org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan=TRACE` to see jpql not sql.

Answer (score 0):

It is not obfuscated, it is simply the statement generates. 
And as most generated code it is optimized for the generation process and not for readability or beauty.

The numbers probably help to create unique column names that also do not hit any length limit.